# Change the playing video

Tags: embed, youtube-api, sample

I'm trying the following code http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#change_the_playing_video

It works well when runned from the playground page. But if I  create a new localfile with the source code provided as sample I get the following error:

ytplayer is not defined

at line 40:

```
if(ytplayer) {
      ytplayer.loadVideoById(videoID);
}
```

It looks like for some reason I don't get access to some part of the javascript needed by the sample.

Is it just me? Or sample code don't run outside the playground page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has to do with same-domain restrictions in Flash. Local files trying to access resources on the internet counts as "cross-domain" access. To whitelist your local file, add it's location to the [global security settings](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html). Click on "Edit locations..." and then "Add location...".

Comment: That's the oddest security settings manager I have ever seen. Ultra counter intuitive. It took me about 10 minutes to realize "That was not a picture"... and other 5 to figure out what to change. Terrible terrible. Actually I think Pat answer was in the same way, but I just didn't get it. Thanks for the link. Could you complement the info with some screenshots? ( I don't know why but I feel I'll forget the answer in a couple of weeks ) Thanks!

Comment: I have added this to the Worst UI ever: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238177/worst-ui-youve-ever-used/1338855#1338855

Answer (score 3):

Pretty sure it's a security problem with flash.  When I try to load it locally, I get the following popup, but it [works fine on my server](http://fullahead.org/work/stackoverflow/google-video.html).

[image]
<sub>(source: [fullahead.org](http://fullahead.org/work/stackoverflow/google-flash-local-error.png))</sub>

If you check out the **Developers** section in the following [Adobe reference](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/135/13530cdd.html), you should be able to get it working.